# webedit:addrendering in Sitecore 8

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, page-editor

In our Sitecore 7 solution we have overridden the `webedit:addrendering` command. Now we are upgrading to Sitecore 8 and I can't seem to find this command in the commands.config. What and where is the `webedit:addrendering` equivalent in Sitecore 8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is `webedit:addrendering` command. It's in `App_Config\Include\Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.config` file now.

Go to `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` of clean **Sitecore 8** and you should see a line like this:

```xml
<command 
    name="webedit:addrendering"
    type="Sitecore.Shell.Applications.WebEdit.Commands.AddRendering, Sitecore.ExperienceEditor"
    patch:source="Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.config"/>
```